# Using the maven assembly plugin with JOGL to create executable jar

Tags: java, maven, jogl, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm trying to create an executable jar for my project that uses [JOGL](http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/).  Previously without JOGL this was easy with the maven-assembly-plugin. I have the following in my application pom:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
    <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
    <archive>
        <manifest>
            <mainClass>org.jbox2d.testbed.framework.jogl.JoglTestbedMain</mainClass>
        </manifest>
    </archive>
</configuration>
```

In the non-jogl project this generates a nice `jbox2d-testbed-2.2.1.2-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies` that is executable (with a different main class in there, of course).

The JOGL project runs just fine in Eclipse with the mavin plugin, I included the jogl dependencies as described [here in the wiki](http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE#Maven).  However, when I use the assembly plugin on this project and launch the `jbox2d-testbed-jogl-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar` I get the following errors:

```
Catched FileNotFoundException: /Users/dmurph/Projects/jbox2d/jbox2d-testbed-jogl/target/jbox2d-testbed-jogl-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies-natives-macosx-universal.jar (No such file or directory), while addNativeJarLibsImpl(classFromJavaJar class com.jogamp.common.os.Platform, classJarURI jar:file:/Users/dmurph/Projects/jbox2d/jbox2d-testbed-jogl/target/jbox2d-testbed-jogl-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/com/jogamp/common/os/Platform.class, nativeJarBaseName jbox2d-testbed-jogl-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies-natives-macosx-universal.jar): [ file:/Users/dmurph/Projects/jbox2d/jbox2d-testbed-jogl/target/jbox2d-testbed-jogl-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar -> file:/Users/dmurph/Projects/jbox2d/jbox2d-testbed-jogl/target/ ] + jbox2d-testbed-jogl-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies-natives-macosx-universal.jar -> slim: jar:file:/Users/dmurph/Projects/jbox2d/jbox2d-testbed-jogl/target/jbox2d-testbed-jogl-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies-natives-macosx-universal.jar!/
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /System/Library/Frameworks/gluegen-rt.Framework/gluegen-rt
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1854)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:795)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1062)
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibraryInternal(JNILibLoaderBase.java:551)
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.access$000(JNILibLoaderBase.java:64)
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase$DefaultAction.loadLibrary(JNILibLoaderBase.java:96)
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibrary(JNILibLoaderBase.java:414)
    at com.jogamp.common.os.DynamicLibraryBundle$GlueJNILibLoader.loadLibrary(DynamicLibraryBundle.java:388)
    at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform$1.run(Platform.java:203)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:173)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.<clinit>(GLProfile.java:82)
    at org.jbox2d.testbed.framework.jogl.JoglPanel.<init>(JoglPanel.java:52)
    at org.jbox2d.testbed.framework.jogl.JoglTestbedMain.main(JoglTestbedMain.java:62)
```

When I decompress the jar, I see all of the required dll and jnilib libraries for JOGL, so is there something extra I need to be doing to get this to work?  I know that JOGL uses a separate-jar system, do I need to change the behavior of the assembly plugin so it can generate the extra jars correctly?

You can grab my project and try it out if you like, it's at https://github.com/dmurph/jbox2d

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [JOGL FAQ](https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/JogAmp_JAR_File_Handling#Fat-Jar), you need to place your native libraries in specific locations within the fat jar. It looks like you are on a Mac, so you need to place your native libraries in this directory *in your jar*:

```
natives/macosx-universal/
```

As mentioned by @gouessej, [here is a complete list of supported architectures and required directories](http://forum.jogamp.org/Packaging-JOGL-projects-to-be-cross-platform-td4031261.html#a4031286).

I think you will need to create a custom [Assembly Descriptor](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html):

```
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html
```

Writing your own descriptor will allow you to place the jars in specific locations, to get the packaging you need.

Comment: I tried this approach to put the JOGL and Gluegen jars in the target jar's root directory, but JOGL still complains that it's unable to load the native components. Can you give explicit instructions that will work with JOGL?

Comment: I've updated my answer. You need to put the native libraries (.so files, etc) in the `natives/macosx-universal/` directory in your jar. All the jars and everything else can go where they normally go. That should be all you need to do.

Comment: I've done this, but JOGL's JNI loader is still unable to find the natives. On the plus side, at least I've found a pure maven way of including the natives directory into the JAR in the correct format.

Comment: You probably did something wrong. If you follow the convention, GlueGen will find the native libraries for sure. JBCP is right.

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow a precise semantic rule to make it work, so that GlueGen is able to locate native libraries within the JARs, extract them and load them:
http://forum.jogamp.org/Packaging-JOGL-projects-to-be-cross-platform-tp4031261p4031286.html

Comment: Is there a way of doing this in Maven?

Comment: Use the assembly plugin and a custom assembly descriptor as I described above. That will give you the control you need to place the native libs in the  correct place.

Comment: @JBCP Thanks. I should put this kind of information into the wiki or in the user's guide.